# Invalid use of function in Haskell with no type error

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, type-inference, type-systems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Vlb.png
thats the image  of the output ^ .
the declarations are here:

```
let add1 x = x + 1
let multi2 x = x * 2
let wtf x = ((add1 multi2) x)
(wtf 3)

<interactive>:8:1:
    No instance for (Num (a0 -> a0)) arising from a use of `it'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
?>
```

Can anyone explain to me why Haskell says that the type of the invalid expression is Num and why it wont print the number?
I can't understand what is going on on the type system.

Comment: It would be nice if you can insert your code and error message here.

Comment: The code I added, but I need you to see the output and error. I cant copy from GHCi.

Comment: @Oded You can copy from Windows' command line window by right clicking, then selecting "mark" from the context menu, marking the area you want to copy, right clicking again and then selecting "copy".

Comment: I have pasted output from GHCi into the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add1 multi2` applies `add1` to a function, but `add1` expects a number. So you might expect this to be an error because functions aren't numbers, but the thing is that they could be. In Haskell a number is a value of a type that's an instance of the `Num` type class and you can add instances whenever you want.

That is, you can write `instance Num (a -> a) where ...` and then functions will be numbers. So now `mult2 + 1` will do something that produces a new function of the same type as `mult2` (what exactly that will be depends on how you defined `+` in the instance of course), so `add1 mult2` produces a function of type `Num a -> a -> a` and applying that function to `x` gives you a value of the same type as `x`.

So what the type `wtf :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => a -> a` is telling you is "Under the condition that you `a` is a numeric type and you define an instance for `Num (a -> a)`", `wtf` will take a number and produce a number of the same type. And when you then actually try to use the function, you get an error because you did not define an instance for `Num (a -> a)`.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*(Re-written somewhat in response to comment)*

Your line of code:

```
((add1 multi2) x)
```

means: apply the `add1` function to the argument `multi2`, then apply the resulting function to the argument `x`. Since adding 1 to a function doesn't make sense, this won't work, so we get a compile-time type error.

The error is explaining that the compiler cannot find a typeclass instance to make functions work like numbers. Numbers must be part of the `Num` typeclass so they can be added, multiplied etc.

```
No instance for (Num (a0 -> a0)
```

In other words, the type `a0-> a0` (which is a function type) doesn't have a `Num` typeclass instance, so adding 1 to it fails. This is a compile-time error; the code is never executed, so GHCi cannot print any output from your function.

The type of your `wtf` function is:

```
wtf :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => a -> a
```

which says:

- Given that `a` is a numeric type
- and `a -> a` (function) is a numeric type
- then `wtf` will take a number and return a number

The second condition fails at compile time because there's no defined way to treat a function as a number.

Comment: I know the syntax for composition, I just want to understand why Haskell didnt complain about the type error and why it tells its a number instead of saying something like "Type error etc..". And why is the type signature like that?

Comment: @ThreeFx It's not a runtime error. It's a compile time error when compiling the expression `wtf 3`.